# Is in-memory persistent store ever fetched if work with MOC tree only

Tags: ios, core-data, persistence

Imagine there is in-memory persistent store.
Imagine there is a tree of `ManagedObjectContext` which root is based on this store.

Imagine I would like to create a new "leaf" of this MOC tree and invoke fetch request on it in non-main, private leaf's MOC queue.

- Would be in-memory persistent store ever fetched in this case? (1)
- Or objects will be obtained only from MOC tree because they are already there? (2)

If (1), could be results of (1) different from results of (2) in any case (e.g. loss of transient property values)?

If (2) never happens, does that mean that for each new such fetch request I will loose the values of transient properties?

Answer (score 0):

(1) Yes. The data has to be fetched from somewhere.

(2) Objects are not "already there".

This is actually really simple. Just imagine a normal Core Data stack with an SQLite persistent store. The only difference to an in-memory store is that the SQLite store is replaced by the in-memory store. That's all there is to it. Whenever the SQLite store *would* have been touched, the in-memory store will be touched.

So regardless of the type of persistent store, you will get exactly the same possible scenarios of managed object contexts on different threads with different state of the data.

Comment: The difference between SQLite store and in-memory store is that there is no objects stored in the store before the app session (with previous MOC tree). So objects stored in the in-memory store were passed through the current MOC tree and probably still remain there alive.

Comment: What do you mean by "MOC tree"? The context is a different concept from the persistent store. For in-memory store, you first have to create objects, but that has nothing to do with nested contexts (presumably what you mean by "MOC tree").

Comment: Yes, I know, I mean if context is retaining objects, with in-memory persistent store that means that all current objects in the persistent store are kept retained in managed object context too. My question was about lifetime of transient property values - can I be sure that having all above (retaining managed object context in the root of the tree, and in-memory persistent store), I will have transient property values not reset between consequent fetch requests.